# Quitar prefijo de varios archivos

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Necesito renombrar recursivamente archivos quitando un texto en especifico. Por ejemplo:

```
mv "prefijo - Filename.html"  "Filename.html"
```

Donde al archivo "prefijo - Filename.html" se le desea quitar el texto **prefijo -**.

Answer (score 2):

Finalmente tras investigar y hacer pruebas el siguiente script me funciono

```
for file in *; do mv "$file" "${file#prefijo}"; done
```

donde **prefijo** es el texto que deseo eliminar

Comment: O sea, en dos minutos has investigado y has hecho las pruebas necesarias para confirmar esta respuesta, mientras la redactabas... te felicito!

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar gnu parallel. Primero tienes que instalarlo, luego puedes hacer algo del estilo:

```
$ find . -mindepth 1 | parallel mv {} '{= s/prefijo - // =}'
```

La explicación del comando es que en `mv {} '{= s/prefijo - // =}'`, la cadena {} es el nombre de la cadena ingresada por el stdout del comando anterior (el nombre del archivo), y `'{= s/prefijo - // =}'` es una expresión tipo Perl sencilla que tan solo quiere decir:

> Reemplaza (s) la expresión regular que busca por la palabra "prefijo -" (/prefijo - /) por la cadena vacía (//).

Puedes encontrar más cosas útiles sobre parallel en su documentación oficial o en el cheat sheet:

https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/parallel_cheat.pdf

También puedes usar `rename`. Primero lo instalas, y después puedes hacer:

```
 $ find . -type f | rename -v 's/prefijo - //'
```